# MonoDroid DialogFragment setStyle

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I'm currentyly trying to convert a DialogFragment from Java to C#.

In Java I can use setStyle( STYLE_NO_TITLE, Theme ); to set the style and the theme of the dialog. But in MonoDroid I can't find a way of doing this. I can find the type DialogFragmentStyle.NoTitle but I can't find anyway to use it to set the style or anyway to set the theme.

Does anybody have any idea of how to do this?

Thanks in advance.
Terry

Comment: Problem in monodroid, they say it will be fixed in 4.2

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android.Ressource.Style and select the style you wish, so your SetStyle could look like:

```
SetStyle(DialogFragmentStyle.Normal, Android.Resource.Style.ThemeHoloLight);
```

Answer (score 0):

When using AndroidX, you should use the following:

```
SetStyle(AndroidX.Fragment.App.DialogFragment.StyleNormal, Android.Resource.Style.ThemeHoloLight);
```